# Datatables.net - Invalid Json Response

Tags: json, datatables, response

I'm having a hard time using DataTables.net. I did a lot of research and it seems that I'm doing right, I tried different combinations, even the debug option on DataTables, but I think that I'm missing some dumb detail, I keep getting "*Invalid Json Response*"

Below I put the HTML, Client Side code, Server Side code, Ajax request/responde headers and Json Response. If someone point what I'm missing here I really appreciate.

**HTML**:

```
<table id="tableQuery" class="table table-striped table-bordered">            
    </table>
```

**Client Side code**:

```
 $('#tableQuery').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            ajax: {                    
                data: {
                    remoteAction: 'GetProtocols'
                },
                dataSrc: 'records'
            },
            columns: [
                {
                    'data': 'protocolo'
                },
                {
                    'data': 'cpf'
                },
                {
                    'data': 'requerente'
                },
                {
                    'data': 'status'
                }
            ]
        });
```

**Server Side Code**:

```
public void GetProtocols(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    context.Response.Write("{ 'records': [{'protocolo': 'protTest1', 'cpf': '123.456.789-00', 'requerente': 'Fulano', 'status': 'Liberado'}]}");
}
```

**Headers**:
[image: Request/Response Headers]
**Json Response**:

`{ 
  'records': [
               {'protocolo': 'protTest1', 'cpf': '123.456.789-00', 'requerente': 'Fulano', 'status': 'Liberado'}
             ]
}`

Answer (score 0):

O got the detail, I was sending the Json using the simple quote *'* instead the double one *"*, that was invalidating the Json.

Thank you all.